# Deep Linking for xamarin app without a website

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, href, deep-linking

I want to redirect my user from email link to a particular app page.
I do not have a subsequent website, my app is independent.
I have tried intent filters and it does take me to the apps main activity but how do i navigate the user to particular activity is my main roadblock.
Am not interested in app linking I just require deep linking.
I want to know how to to navigate to the particular activity from the link itself directly.

I have tried intent filters in mainactivity.cs along with datascheme.
In my implementation when i send an link inside the email and i click OS asks me how should I proceed 
1.By app or 2. Chrome This is fine.
But when i click on app it opens from the main activity.

```
 [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                       AutoVerify = true,
                       Categories = new[]
                       {
                            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
                       },
                       DataScheme = "http",
                       DataPathPrefix = "",
                       DataHost = "MyAppName")]
```

Comment: Are you talking about open a particular Forms' Page or an Android Activity?

Comment: I want to redirect my user to a particular page from an email link.
Ex. Go ahead and copy it, then click here to confirm your account. something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the url you click is `http://myappname?destination=a`, you can get the data in activity through:

```
if (Intent.Data != null)
{
    var host = Intent.Data.EncodedAuthority;
    var parameter = Intent.Data.GetQueryParameter("destination");
}
```

As you are using Xamarin.Forms, you should navigate to the specify page on Forms. [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) is a good choice.

Firstly, register it in App on Forms project:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, "Navigate", (sender, args) =>
    {
        if ((string)args == "a")
        {
            MainPage = new SecondPage();

            // or (MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new SecondPage());
        }
    });
}
```

Fire this messaging center when you recieve the data:

```
if (host == "myappname")
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "Navigate", parameter);
}
```

**Update**

If you don't want to use MessagingCenter. Define a public method in App like:

```
public void MoveToPage(string pageName)
{
    if (pageName == "a")
    {
        MainPage = new SecondPage();
        // or (MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
}
```

Then call this when `Intent.Data != null` in MainActivity:

```
var formsApp = new App();
LoadApplication(formsApp);
if (Intent.Data != null)
{
    var host = Intent.Data.EncodedAuthority;
    var parameter = Intent.Data.GetQueryParameter("destination");

    formsApp.MovePage(parameter);
}
```

Comment: my url will not start with http:// instead it will start with the app name itself "myappname://"

Comment: @UtkarshNadgouda You can. But you have to change your `DataScheme` to myappname. And then use `myappname://myappname` as your `DataHost` is also myappname.

Comment: It does work that way but again my question is how do i redirect to specific page rather than opening the main activity?

Comment: @UtkarshNadgouda Have you checked my answer above? We can use messaging center to open a new page on Forms.

Comment: @UtkarshNadgouda If you don't like MessagingCenter, I post an update above.